# Converting a pointer C# type to F#?

Tags: f#

I am just a beginner in programing i wish covert some code from C# to F#,

I have encotered this code:

```
float[] v1=new float[10]
```

I need to use this pointer to pass to the function:

```
ComputeBuffer<float> bufV1 = 
  new ComputeBuffer<float>(Context, ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadWrite |
         ComputeMemoryFlags.UseHostPointer, v1);
```

If i creat an array in F# like this:

```
let v1 = [| 1.0..10.0 |]
```

and call now the funaction like this:

```
let bufV1 = new ComputeBuffer<float>(Context, 
    ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadWrite ||| 
        ComputeMemoryFlags.UseHostPointer, v1)
```

Is it an error?? How do i pass a pointer??

Answer (score 5):

(In .NET, we call these things **references** to objects; `v1` is a reference to an array object.  Pointers are something different.)

Note that what F# refers to as `float` is what C# calls a `double`.  You might need

```
let v1 = [| 1.0f .. 10.0f |]
```

where the `f` suffix makes the values be F# `float32`s (e.g. C# `float`s).

Comment: if in C# the type in float what should it be in F#

Comment: in F# it is called `float32` (or you can use the full .NET name, `System.Float`, which is the same for all languages)

Comment: I tried to do 
"open System.Float"
and got "error FS0039: The namespace 'Float' is not defined"

what can i do?

Comment: Its Ok thank you very much i did not use the "open System.Float", I had just changed to float32, looks like it is working

Answer (score 2):

not an error.

Need to point out that `v1` is not a pointer, it is an object in .Net.

Comment: Thank you very much every one, the answers are working and helping me to advance with porting the code