# Converting a C# code to F#

Tags: c#, f#

I am just a beginner in programing i wish covert some code from C# to F#,

I have encotered this code:

```
float[] v1=new float[10];

...

//Enqueue the Execute command. 
Queue.Execute(kernelVecSum, null, **new long[] { v1.Length }**, null, null);
```

I have previously ask how to convert the `v1` object, 
I think i know how,
But how do i use the function call especially the `new long[] { v1.Length }` part of the function argument, what does `new long[] { v1.Length }` mean??

I have created **v1** like this `let v1 = [| for i in 1.0 .. 10.0 -> 2.0 * i |]`

Is it correct?
or should i use **v1** like this `let v1 = ref [| for i in 1.0 .. 10.0 -> 2.0 * i |]` ?

Answer (score 2):

This is really more of a C# question... you might tag it as such.

In C#

```
new long[] { v1.Length }
```

creates a new array of `long`s that contains a single element whose value is `v1.Length`.  In F# it would be e.g.

```
[| int64 v1.Length |]
```

(In any case, no, you don't want the `ref` in the F# code.  And you still have not corrected the data type as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981126/converting-a-pointer-c-type-to-f).)

Comment: Thank you very much every one, the answers are working and helping me to advance with porting the code

Answer (score 0):

```
Queue.Execute(kernelVecSum, null, [| int64 (v1.Length) |], null, null)
```

?

Comment: That creates an array of `v1.Length` elements all initialized to zero, which is not what the C# code does.

Comment: Thank you very much every one, the answers are working and helping me to advance with porting the code